# Gravitational effect of larger solar system to Earth orbit

Tags: newtonian-gravity, orbital-motion, earth, sun, solar-system

Let's say our solar system enters to gravitational area of a larger solar system. Does Earth's orbit of sun get affected from this case?

Comment: Yes. That's the answer but it's too short to even post on its own as a comment.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It depends on the mass of the larger solar system and the distance of Earth from it.
F=GMm/r^2
G: Universal gravitational constant 
M: Mass of the sun or the other solar system
m:Mass of Earth
r:Distance from the source of gravitational field
If F exerted by the other solar system is stronger by that exerted by the sun,Earths orbit will be affected.

Comment: honestly, they are not the moderators and they should not act like one by flagging the answers as duplicate. No one pays them for that.

Comment: No one pays anybody on this site. We all just want to make it so that searching the site for answers isn't a living hell.